# How to get data from a service thats already running? 

Tags: android

I have a service that runs once the app starts and I was wondering how can I get data from that service to an activity at anytime without having to restart the service

Answer (score 5):

No offense, but the "Messenger" and "binding" way kept me busy for about 2 days to figure out. Not that it's wrong, but it overcomplicated things for me.

In my opinion its easier for a service to broadcast the data so that an Activity can just access the data when available.
Do the tutorial on this link:
http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/comment-page-1/#comment-734

(took me 10minutes to figure out and implement... excellent tutorial)

Answer (score 4):

If the service is already running, calling `startService()` does not "restart the service". It simply sends a command to be picked up by the service in `onStartCommand()`. So, you can send a command that triggers the service to do something on the activity's behalf, which could involve communications from the service back to the activity (e.g., via a `Messenger`).

Or, as @Tom Dignan points out, you can bind to the service. Just be a bit careful as you deal with configuration changes, like when the user rotates the screen.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you bind the service. Extensive information can be found in the Android docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (end of 2013) there are better solutions to getting a reference to a running service in Android, just use a library like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [EventBus](http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/).

Add an eventbus in your activity and service, implement the `onEvent()` method on both sides, create one or two `xyzEvent` classes (`xyz` = your event name), register the activity and service references in the eventbus (the 'this').

Post an event towards the service from your activity on the eventbus, catch it in the `onEvent` method of your service, post a new event back towards the activity, catch it in the `onEvent` method of your activity: now you have your service reference (the `this` of the service) available within the activity.

All set and done without any fuss. Activity and Service pretty decoupled and easy to implement. Nothing special about it. No direct binding, no Messengers, no AIDL. Just the old-fasioned K.I.S.S. principle.

Now you have a reference to your service from within your activity and can call any direct method available within the service.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a running service to the activity (e.g. when clicking a button), you should use Bounded Service , You bind to a service, get a reference to it and call a public method. see more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)  and [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example)

To send data from service to activity you can use Handlers/Messenger using threads or broadcast intents and broadcast receivers.